# shell script to parse log file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I am given a log file(see below), I need to make it to this format using bash script:

```
title   pdfspool date  rip date   bmpspool date  CLAB date
Sometitle12  10/09/23 00:56:40 10/9/23 0:56:46  10/9/23 0:56:50  10/9/23 1:01:13
```

log file

```
!!Begin    
Source aserver:pdf_spool:the, Job 844b015e0043469e, Inst 844b015e0043469e    
Title Sometitle12.pdf    
Action Started Received, Ok Date 10/09/23 00:56:40    
For Administrator    
(8) DataType = PDF    
(17) Source = srv01:aserver:file_input:0    
!!End    
!!Begin    
Source aserver:rip:rip1, Job 844b015e0043469e, Inst 844b015e004346a0    
Title Sometitle12.pdf Cyan 1    
Action Started Transmit, Ok Date 10/09/23 00:56:46    
For Administrator    
(8) DataType = Bitmap    
(1) Destination = srv01:bserver:bmp_spool:the    
(4) Parent = 844b015e0043469e/844b015e0043469e    
!!End    
!!Begin    
Source bserver:bmp_spool:the, Job 844b015e0043469e, Inst 844b015e004346a0    
Title Sometitle12.pdf Cyan 1    
Action Started Received, Ok Date 10/09/23 00:56:50    
For Administrator    
(8) DataType = Bitmap    
(17) Source = srv01:aserver:rip:rip1    
!!End    
!!Begin    
Source bserver:bmp_spool:the, Job 844b015e0043469e, Inst 844b015e004346a0    
Title Sometitle12.pdf Cyan 1    
Action Atomic Accepted, Ok Date 10/09/23 01:01:13    
For Administrator    
(8) DataType = Bitmap    
(2) Source Queue = ^03Newspaper ltd(MP)^Date - 24MP^Site - N^    
(5) Requested By = clab    
(15) Approval Status = Waiting Approved    
 Changed from Waiting to Approved by clab.   
!!End
```

Ideas welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{}
/Action Started Received/ && !c{ pdfspooldate=$(NF-1)$NF ;c++}
/Action Started Received/ && c{ bmppooldate=$(NF-1)$NF ;c=0}
/Action Started Transmit/{ ripdate=$(NF-1)$NF }
/title/ { title=$2}
/Action Atomic Accepted/{ clabdate=$(NF-1)$NF }
END{ print title,pdfspooldate,ripdate,clabdate }' file
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great, except that you skipped bmpspool date which has the same pattern as pdfspooldate. How to differentiate them?

Comment: How do I parse now a file with multiple pieces of that log?
By, the way in the counter I used $c=2 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk. Write a state machine. Switch states when you see `/^!!Begin$/`, record your data, and dump your output and switch back when you see `/^!!End$/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Perl/Python/Ruby, you should able to use regular expression matching in one line (the matching part).  Use the multiline mode where a `.` will match the newline character.  I think awk or sed should be able to use regular expression the same way:

for example, in Ruby:

```
s = <<TEXT
!!Begin
Something haha
Title Good Bad Ugly
Date 1/1/2008
!!End
!!Begin
Other info
Title Iron Man
Date 2/2/2010
TEXT

result = s.scan(/^!!Begin.*?^Title\s+([^\n]*).*?^Date\s+([^\n]*)/m)

p result

result.each do |arr|
  puts arr.join(' ')
end
```

output:

```
$ ruby try.rb 
[["Good Bad Ugly", "1/1/2008"], ["Iron Man", "2/2/2010"]]
Good Bad Ugly 1/1/2008
Iron Man 2/2/2010
```

Comment: how do you read text file and pass it to "s" variable here? get_file_as_text didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Perl with `$/ = "!!End"`, then parse each paragraph.